# Core Data Set Relationship from Inverse

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a bunch of code that sets Core Data relationships via the inverse instead of the "addWhateverObject" methods. This usually works well in all of my applications, but I have one app where the relationships are being lost when the NSManagedObject context is being saved.

My question is setting a relationship in Core Data via the relationship's inverse valid or do you have to use the accessor methods to add objects to the relationship?

Thanks!

Comment: have look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764125/does-every-core-data-relationship-have-to-have-an-inverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the inverse is valid. Core data does all of the appropriate updating for you when you do that. See the comments on this question [Core Data To-Many Relationship Creating Duplicates When Adding Object to Parent Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551842/core-data-to-many-relationship-creating-duplicates-when-adding-object-to-parent)